# SQL - Displaying 3 different counts on one query

Tags: mysql, sql

Each of these three queries work on their own. However, I'd like all three COUNTS to be displayed in the same query. They are identical except for slight variations in the WHERE statement.

```
/* Display Total Message Count */
SELECT People.Name, COUNT(Messages.SenderID) as "Total Messages Sent"
FROM Ballers.Messages JOIN Ballers.People
WHERE Messages.SenderID = People.ID
GROUP BY People.Name;

/* Display Text Message Count */
SELECT People.Name, COUNT(Messages.SenderID) as "Text Messages Sent"
FROM Ballers.Messages JOIN Ballers.People
WHERE Messages.SenderID = People.ID AND Type = "Text"
GROUP BY People.Name;

/* Display Picture Message Count */
SELECT People.Name, COUNT(Messages.SenderID) as "Picture Messages Sent"
FROM Ballers.Messages JOIN Ballers.People
WHERE Messages.SenderID = People.ID AND Type = "Picture"
GROUP BY People.Name;
```

I have not been successful in outputting all three queries on the same table. I've tried a lot of different things but all have given me errors. I'm pretty new to SQL and I don't yet fully grasp how everything works. Here is one example of failed code:

```
/* Display All Message Counts, 3 Queries In One */
SELECT 
People.Name, 
(COUNT(Messages.SenderID) as "Messages Sent"
WHERE Messages.SenderID = People.ID),
(COUNT(Messages.SenderID) as "Text Messages Sent"
WHERE Messages.SenderID = People.ID AND Type = "Text"), 
(COUNT(Messages.SenderID) as "Picture Messages Sent"
WHERE Messages.SenderID = People.ID AND Type = "Picture")
FROM Ballers.Messages JOIN Ballers.People
GROUP BY People.Name;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not tested, but something along these lines should work:

```
SELECT People.Name,
COUNT(*) AS AllMessages,
SUM(CASE WHEN Type='Text' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TextMessages,
SUM(CASE WHEN Type='Picture' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PictureMessages
FROM Ballers.Messages JOIN Ballers.People ON People.ID=Messages.SenderID
GROUP BY People.Name
```

Comment: nailed it. Thank you very much. Just so I'm clear about what is going on in the code, let me try to explain it back and you let me know if I'm right. Count(*) counts everything in the ON statement. The next two lines basically are doing an if statement for their own counts (1 means increment, null means don't? Or could you put a 2 where the 1 is and would it increment the count by 2 each time?). Also, what does the END statement do?

Comment: @sakau2007 You've got it: a sort of if-statement on each row. END closes the statement beginning with CASE. I've changed the code somewhat, using SUM to SUM all the 1's together. COUNT simply counts the number of results, so anything but NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT
 `People1`.`Name`,
 COUNT(`Messages1`.`SenderId`) as `TotalMessagesSent`,
 COUNT(`Messages2`.`SenderId`) as `TextMessagesSent`,
 COUNT(`Messages3`.`SenderId`) as `PictureMessagesSent`
FROM
 `Messages` as `Messages1`
 JOIN `People` as `People1` ON (`Messages1`.`SenderId` = `People1`.`ID`),
 `Messages` as `Messages2`
 JOIN `People` as `People2` ON (`Messages2`.`SenderId` = `People2`.`ID` AND `Type`='Text'),
`Messages` as `Messages3`
 JOIN `People` as `People3` ON (`Messages3.`SenderId` = `People3`.`ID` AND `Type`='Pictures')
GROUP BY
 `People1`.`Name`
```

OR select just from the people table and join the messages:

```
SELECT
 `People`.`Name`,
 COUNT(`Messages1`.`SenderId`) as `TotalMessagesSent`,
 COUNT(`Messages2`.`SenderId`) as `TextMessagesSent`,
 COUNT(`Messages3`.`SenderId`) as `PictureMessagesSent`
FROM
 `People`
 JOIN `Messages` as `Messages1` ON (`Messages1`.`SenderId` = `People`.`ID`)
 JOIN `Messages` as `Messages2` ON (`Messages2`.`SenderId` = `People`.`ID` AND `Type`='Text')
 JOIN `Messages` as `Messages3` ON (`Messages3.`SenderId` = `People`.`ID` AND `Type`='Pictures')
GROUP BY
 `People`.`Name`
```

maybe it's not complete and it's not tested.